# How can I get my SQL query to delete the most recent record?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete the most recent record where the job_id is equal to the id from jobs where the status is paused and know of no such functionality. Is there a way to do this?

```
DELETE FROM
  records
WHERE
  **due_date = most recent**
  AND job_id IN (
    SELECT
      id
    FROM
      jobs
    WHERE
      status = 'paused'
  )
```

Comment: Please let us know which actual _database_ you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).  Also, include some sample data if possible.

Comment: You can `order by due_date desc`, then `limit 1` your delete.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would also help.  Most recent of *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
DELETE FROM records WHERE due_date IN 
( SELECT due_date FROM records ORDER BY due_date DESC LIMIT 1) 
and job_id IN (SELECT id FROM jobs WHERE status = 'paused') ;
```

I am assuming below table schema, Please correct if otherwise

```
CREATE TABLE records(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, due_date date,name varchar2,job_id integer);
CREATE TABLE jobs(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, status varchar2);


INSERT INTO records VALUES(1,'17/12/2015','1','3');
INSERT INTO records VALUES(2,'17/12/2020','2','3');

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(3,'paused');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES(4,'paused');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I can't validate this, so I am hesitant to run this in the DB, which is MYSQL. Could this just be written with a single IN statement?

Something I can validate on https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: You can use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php to create dummy tables and validate.